# How to use PHP to display 50 random images from hundreds?

Tags: php, database, random, duplicates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast)

There are many varying examples across the web, but I am hoping someone has a solution that fits what I am looking for... Surely I cannot be the only one!

I am building a photography website and want to display 50+ image thumbnails on the landing page. The kicker is that I want it to display pictures randomly using PHP and without duplication. I also want each image to have its own, unique href and title params.

So, I have created a mySQL table that holds:

```
id image_path, image_href, image_title
```

I was figuring I would easily re-size the images on my own and put them in a folder in the root directory and then call it in the row image_path.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this the most efficient way? I have heard that rand() sucks when the database gets big. The database will grow to tens of thousands of images.

Let me know if you need/want clarification.

Thanks!!!

Edit: I may have come across the answer in my research, but I'm pretty new to PHP... :)

Comment: Why not use MySQL's `RAND` when returning the results? Doing it with the database is better than doing it with PHP.

Comment: @DylanCross I heard that it gets really slow when your database is large.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could query the database, sort the results by `RAND()` and select the top 50:

```
SELECT id, image_path, image_href, image_title 
FROM table 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 50
```

This guarantees no duplicate results unless your table itself has duplicates.

A faster method is outlined in this question: [MySQL select 10 random rows from 600K rows fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329396/mysql-select-10-random-rows-from-600k-rows-fast)

Comment: I really love typing an answer and discarding it after I see that there's a way more elegant way of doing things, thanks!

Comment: @blender I read that rand() gets real slow when the table is large...

Comment: @doobada: Read the answers to the question I linked to at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @Blender I didn't see it first time around, thanks for the link. How would I write the code to place the images in separate divs on the page? I don't want it to just spit out the 50 images in one div...

Comment: @doobada: I don't use PHP anymore so I'm not sure what are some good sites to link to, but that info is covered in a basic PHP/MySQL tutorial.

Comment: @Blender Thanks for the help! If you stumble on a good tut, please send it on over.